# How can I make a Linq extension for objects with a specific attribute?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, extension-methods

I'm interested in making a extension for objects that have an attribute (in this case `[ProtoContract]`).

For example, the extension would work on:

```
[ProtoContract]
class myClass{
     //stuff
}
```

... but not on ...

```
class someRandomClass
{
}
```

The difference here is that usually you can make a extension function like this:

```
public static byte[] Serialize<T>(this T instance){
```

... but in this case I want it to only work on classes with the `[ProtoContract]` attribute.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to filter that with the `where`, you'll just have to throw an exception. Consider this:

```
public static byte[] Serialize<T>(this T instance)
{
    if (!Attribute.IsDefined(typeof(T), typeof(ProtoContractAttribute)))
    {
        throw new Exception(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't compile. You want `typeof(T)` - and it's simpler to use `IsDefined` rather than calling `GetCustomAttributes`.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I meant to call that off the `TypeInfo`, but missed the call to `GetType()`, my apologies. Looking up the `IsDefined` now.

Comment: @JonSkeet, thanks so much for the `IsDefined` interface! I've got some code I wrote last night actually that builds SQL dynamically with attributes, this is **so much easier!**

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud: Yes, it's certainly handy :)

Comment: @JonSkeet I have had the famous Jon Skeet respond to my question! I am honored.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud Are you sure you don't want to use http://www.fluentnhibernate.org/ for your database mapping?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to make a runtime check with reflection inside youre `Serialize` method, but not to make the check compile time since attributes are not part of the type's signature.

If you want to have compile time checking you would have to use a (slightly ugly) interface with no methods instead of an attribute.

Comment: Anyone viewing this answer - please refer to Jon Skeet's comments on the below answer.